# with smart table I display "male" if value = 0 and "female" if value = 1 in

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I need something like this with angularjs and smart table

```
<tbody ng-show="!mc.isLoading">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in mc.displayed" st-select-row="row">
           if {{row.userName}} ==0
                <td>male</td>
           else
              <td>female</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ngIf` or `ngShow` directive.

The example below is using `ngIf`.

```
<tbody ng-show="!mc.isLoading">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in mc.displayed" st-select-row="row">
        <td ng-if="row.userName === 0">male</td>
        <td ng-if="row.userName === 1">female</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to apply a directive like `ng-if` if you only want to conditionally display a word/string, angular expressions are also a good choice

`{{row.userName === 0 ? 'male' : 'female'}}`

Answer (score 0):

you can make `<td ng-show="row.userName == 0">male</td>`

`<td ng-hide="row.userName == 1">Female</td>`